# how do i get the background color to update automatically with this javascript?

Tags: javascript

the following javascript is supposed to adjust the background color based on the current time, with different changes happening on the minute, second and hour.

right now, the changes only happen when i reload the page each time.

how do i get the changes to happen dynamically as time changes?

```
var body = document.getElementById("body");
var minute = 0;


function currentTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    console.log(today);
    hour = today.getHours();
    minute = today.getMinutes();
    second = today.getSeconds();

    console.log(minute);
}

function changeColor() {
    console.log("Minute: " + second);
    color_valueR = Math.floor(second * 2.25); // scale up to 255 and convert to integer
    color_valueG = Math.floor(minute * 3.25); // scale up to 255 and convert to integer
    color_valueB = Math.floor(hour * 4.25); // scale up to 255 and convert to integer

    rgb = "rgb(" + color_valueR + ", " + color_valueG + ", " + color_valueB + ")"; // create RGB string
    console.log(rgb);
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background = rgb; // set background color
}

function setScene() {
    currentTime();
    changeColor();
}

window.addEventListener("load", setScene, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

load only fires once; instead, you want to set an interval, which repeatedly calls code every so often, such as:

```
setInterval(function() { changeColor(); }, 1000); //1000= 1 second
```

Which you would call your method to check and set the color.

Comment: `setTimeout` also only fires once. You're probably thinking of `setInterval`. And you can shorten it. `setInterval(changeColor, 1000);`. No need for the anonymous function.

Comment: never-mind all set! and is there a good way to set logic so once it hits 255 it will start going back down?

Comment: Yes, I said that in my question, but screwed it up :-)